# Is the lightning:map component enabled in Lightning Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-community

It appears the new lightning:map component released in Winter '19 works in LEX, but isn't visible to guest or logged in users in a lightning community.

Can anyone confirm that this is true?  Is there a configuration setting to enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone confirm that this is true? Is there a configuration setting
>   to enable it?

Not true - The lightning:map component is available for guests and logged-in users, there is no configuration to set it up.

This might be most likely due to a permission issue for the profiles.

sample map component for guest user can be found here:

https://coffee-joe-developer-edition.na59.force.com/s/map

when you say 'not visible' it is possible that it is not rendering due to data not being passed to it due to a permission issue, if you do not add any sort of validation or debugging in your code, it will be hard to tell why the component is not rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - that was the encouragement I needed to keep debugging.  The child component loading sequence turned out to be the culprit - a little refactoring and the component renders just fine.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation in the link [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:map/example) it says clearly that its avaliable for communities.

The only caveat is your component needs to use API version 44 and greater.

I haven't tried it but from documentation it should be possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue : in Communities, the lightning:map does not acknowledge any relaxed CSP security setting :

- see
  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001FSlqQAG&title=lightning-map-does-not-work-in-communities

No workaround as of today